# Books About Development Fundamentals (Mainly Web)

Tags: web

I'm a 24yo Web Developer trying to improve my knowledge in this field.
I've been working on web since I was 12 and feel like I lack some fundamentals. 
Many times I'm being rejected in interviews not because lack of talent, programming knowledge or a small portfolio (In fact, my portfolio is pretty big for a 24 yo dev), but because I can't answer many fundamental questions such as difference between/terminology about CRUD, REST, SOAP, OOP-related questions and such..

Going to university right now is impossible for many reasons so I was trying to get my hands on some books about dev fundamentals (mainly oriented to web dev). What are the best ones, and why? Which resources (Shouldn't necessary be books) should I look deeply into? And in the end.. What suggestions could you give to become a better developer?

Comment: questions asking for external resources is off topic

Comment: Providing the same question without asking for external resources is impossible. Generally asking "How to become a better developer?" wouldn't provide any useful or proper answer without external resources.. I guess this case is not replicable in a "safe and non off-topic" way.

Comment: in which case, the question doesnt belong on this site of SO

Comment: I don't think providing external resources should be flagged as spam, as not every answer can be answered without those.

Comment: but with the terms of the site, this type of question is off topic

Answer (score -1):

I can only share from my own experience. During technical interviews, i had a cheat sheet printed and ready. That helped a lot on the telephone interview but also as a study guide. I can recommend the "PHP Zend Certification Study Guide" and php-fig.org to freshen up on Design Patterns and other things.

When the interviewer thinks you are qualified, you need to write code anyway. During the code writing you will probably write in OOP PHP with no framework. Prepare a simple mvc with some simple crud functionality, sessions and user login.

Comment: This is not something I lack knowledge about.. I made my own MVC and know/work with many Design Patterns, it's something else what I'm looking for, but still thank you for your useful answer.